# Storing a game map in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

A map will be tile based, and will have the following two primary data storage requirements

- List of 'walkable' tiles (this could be represented by a single string of 0s & 1s that correspond to the NxN tiles?)
- List of image paths that map to those NxN tiles

My noobie thoughts

- Each "map" is a row in the Maps table.
- The 'walkable' tiles could be stored as a single string. I've read that this is generally advised against but don't know of a better way to represent this since the values can only be one of two values.
- I'm not sure how to store the NxN image path strings to be associated with the tiles.

Very inexperienced with SQL and data storage architecture in general so I'd like to learn from suggestions on how to set this scheme up.

Comment: why not have a `y`-coordinate, an `x`-coordinate and then the tiles itself?

Comment: Do you mean setting up a Tile table where each entry has an X,Y coordinate, image-path, and walkable flag. Then each tile has a foreign key to the map?

Comment: Ideally we'd want to re-use tiles across multiple maps, so baking in coordinate data and walkability flags would go against that.

Comment: How are you going to parse this to a front end client? Java script, html5, other? There is some better solutions if you can provide more information.

Answer (score 5):

In broad terms, I'd approach this problem like this:

```
Tiles
  Tile_ID
  Tile_Name(?)
  Walkable
  Image_Path

Maps
  Map_ID
  Map_Name

Map_Tiles
  Map_ID
  Tile_ID
  X_Coordinate
  Y_Coordinate
  Orientation
  Walkable(?)
```

Things you don't want to do, according to relational design principles:

- Force multiple data elements (tiles) into a single row (i.e. don't
  put all of the map's tiles in a single row).
- Overload a single field with multiple data elements (i.e. don't put all of the map's tiles into a single field).

Answer (score 1):

If I guess the following correctly:

- the important data of a tile for your application can be stored in a string
- you have several maps, where tiles can be reused
- every map has connections between tiles in some order (simplified like north of Tile 217  lies 194, south lies 217). Those 'directions' could be seen as of some small overall possible list, like (North, northeast, east... ,south, up, down, special1, special2)?

Then I would go for a table `maps`, a table `tiles` and a table `connections`. In `map` you store the maps, in `tiles` the tiles with their overall properties and in `connections` you store:

```
CREATE TABLE connection 
(  id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key, 
   at_tile int(11), //reference to the tile where you come from
   direction enum('N','NE','UP',"SP1","SP5), // and so on
   to_tile int(11)
)
```

and add some indices as the system grows.